# Where is my mistake solving a non-linear PDE with the method of characteristics?

Tags: characteristics, partial-differential-equations

The non-linear PDE that I would like to solve is:

\begin{align}
u^2_{x_1} - u^2_{x_2} &= 2u  \label{DGL1} \\
u(0,x_2) &= (1+x_2)^2 \label{DGL2}.
\end{align}

We define the notion

\begin{align*}
    z(s) &= u(x(s))\\
    p(s) &= (p_1(s),p_2(s)) = (u_{x_1}(x(s)), u_{x_2}(x(s)))).
\end{align*}

With this notion we have

\begin{align*}
z(0) = u(x(0)) = u(0,x_0) = (1+x_0)^2.
\end{align*}

So we can transfrom the PDE into this parameterized PDE:
\begin{equation*}
    F(p,z,x) = p_1^2 - p_2^2 - 2z.
\end{equation*}

We can solve this with the method of characteristics:
\begin{align*}
    \dot{p}(s) &= - \begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        0
    \end{pmatrix} -(-2)\begin{pmatrix}
        p_1\\
        p_2
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2p_1, \, 2p_2 \end{pmatrix} \\
    \dot{z}(s) &= \begin{pmatrix}
        2p_1, \, -2p_2
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        p_1\\
        p_2
    \end{pmatrix} = 2p_1^2 - 2p_2^2 = 2\left(p_1^2 - p_2^2\right).
\end{align*}

Since $\dot{x}_1 = 2p_1 = \dot{p}_1$ is valid with $x_1(s=0)=0$, we have
\begin{align*}
    &x_1(s) = p_{10}(e^{2s}-1)\\
    \Rightarrow \quad &\dot{x}_1 = 2p_{10}e^{2s} = 2p_1 = \dot{p}_1\\
    \Rightarrow \quad &p_1 = p_{10}e^{2s}.
\end{align*}

Since $\dot{x}_2 = -2p_2 = - \dot{p}_2$ is valid, we have $x_2(s=0)=x_0$, we have
\begin{align*}
    &x_2(s) = -p_{20}\left(e^{2s}-1\right) + x_0\\
    \Rightarrow \quad &\dot{x}_2 = -2p_{20}e^{2s} = -2p_2 = -\dot{p}_2\\
    \Rightarrow \quad &p_2 = p_{20}e^{2s}.
\end{align*}

We can use this now for $\dot{z}(s)$ and $z(s)$ respectively:
\begin{align*}
    \dot{z}(s) &= 2\left(p_1^2 - p_2^2\right)\\
    &= 2\left((p_{10}e^{2s})^2 - (p_{20}e^{2s})^2\right)\\
    &= 2p_{10}^2e^{4s} - 2p_{20}^2e^{4s}\\
    \Rightarrow \quad z(s) &= \tfrac{1}{2}p_{10}^2e^{4s} - \tfrac{1}{2}p_{20}^2e^{4s} + z_0.
\end{align*}

We have $z_0 = z(0) = u(x(0)) = u(0,x_0) = (1+x_0)^2$.

Now let us calculate $p(0)=(p_{10},p_{20})$:
\begin{align*}
    &p_{20} = p_2(0) = u_{x_2}(x(0)) = u_{x_2}((0,x_0)) = 2(1+x_0)  \quad \text{and}\\
    &p_{10}^2 - p_{20}^2 = u_{x_1}^2((0,x_0)) - u_{x_2}^2((0,x_0)) \underbrace{=}_{PDE} 2u(0,x_0) = 2z(x(0)) = 2z_0 = 2(1+x_0)^2\\
    \Rightarrow \quad &p_{10}^2 - p_{20}^2 = p_{10}^2 - 4(1+x_0)^2 = 2(1+x_0)^2\\
    \Leftrightarrow \quad &p_{10}^2 = 6(1+x_0)^2\\
    \Leftrightarrow \quad &p_{10} = \sqrt{6}(1+x_0).
\end{align*}

With $p_{10}$ and $p_{20}$, we can calculate $x(s)$, $z(s)$ und $p(s)$:

\begin{align*}
    x_1(s) &= \sqrt{6}(1+x_0)(e^{2s}-1)\\
    x_2(s) &= -2(1+x_0)(e^{2s}-1) + x_0\\
    z(s) &= \tfrac{1}{2}6(1+x_0)^2e^{4s} - \tfrac{1}{2}4(1+x_0)^2e^{4s} + (1+x_0)^2\\
    &=(1+x_0)^2(e^{4s}+1)\\
    p_1(s) &= \sqrt{6}(1+x_0)e^{2s}\\
    p_2(s) &= 2(1+x_0)e^{2s}.
\end{align*}

Let $(x,y) \in \Omega := \mathbb{R}^2$ be arbitrary and select $s$ u
and $x_0$:
\begin{align*}
        (x,y) = (x_1(s), \, x_2(s)) = (\sqrt{6}(1+x_0)(e^{2s}-1), \, -2(1+x_0)(e^{2s}-1) + x_0).
\end{align*}
This is a linear equation system and can be solved by $x_0$ and $e^{2s}$:
\begin{align*}
    x_0 = y+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}}, \qquad e^{2s} = \frac{x}{\left(y+1+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\sqrt{6}}+1.
\end{align*}

Finally, we can solve the desired function $u(x,y)$:
\begin{align*}
    u(x,y) &= u(x_1(s), x_2(s)) = z(s)\\
    &= (1+x_0)^2\left((e^{2s}\right)^2+1)\\
    &= \left(1+y+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}}\right)^2 \left(\left(\frac{x}{ (y+1+ \frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}} ) \sqrt{6} }+1\right)^2+1\right).
\end{align*}

However, if I want to verify this $u(x,y)$ with the PDEs at the beginning, it doesn't add up! So I must have done something wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

Please also comment on anything thats strange.

Comment: The difficulty is due to an ambiguity in the wording of the question. What is the correst condition ? Is it $u(0,x_2) = (1+x_2^2)$ or is it $u(0,x_0) = (1+x_0)^2$ ? Both are contradictory at the point $(x_1=0\:,\:x_2=x_0)$.

Comment: The correction condition is $u(0,x_2) = (1+x_2)^2$. If we use the notion $z(s) = u(x(s))$, then $z(0) = u(x(0)) = u(0,x_0) = (1+x_2)^2$. Thanks, I will be more clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake: $z(0)$ isn't equal to $z_0$.

It must be  \begin{align*} z(s) &= \tfrac{1}{2}p_{10}^2\left(e^{4s}-1\right) - \tfrac{1}{2}p_{20}^2\left(e^{4s}-1\right) + z_0,
\end{align*}

so that $z_0 = z(0) = u(x(0)) = u(0,x_0) = (1+x_0)^2$ is right.

This leads to the right solution

\begin{align*}
    u(x,y) &= u(x_1(s), x_2(s)) = z(s)\\
    &= (1+x_0)^2\left(e^{2s}\right)^2\\
    &= \left(1+y+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}}\right)^2 \left(\frac{x}{ (y+1+ \frac{2x}{\sqrt{6}} ) \sqrt{6} }+1\right)^2\\
    &\underbrace{=}_{WolframAlpha} \left( \frac{\sqrt{6}x}{2}  + y +1   \right)^2.
\end{align*}